# Alterar a quantidade e alterar o valor final do carrinho

Tags: javascript, jquery

Colegas,

Tenho esse carrinho:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de fazer com que ao adicionar ou diminuir a quantidade do carrinho (img 1), alterasse o subtotal e o total da compra (img 2 e 3) sem refresh na página. O código que tenho da img 1 segue abaixo:

Os valores estão armazenados dessa forma:

```
<td class="invert">R$<span id="produto">200,00</span></td>
<td class="invert">R$<span id="produto">270,00</span></td>
<td class="invert">R$<span id="produto">212,00</span></td>
```

Os botões da quantidade estão da forma abaixo:

```
   <div class="quantity">
      <div class="quantity-select">
         <div class="entry value-minus">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="entry value"><span>1</span></div>
       <div class="entry value-plus active">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
       <script>
        $('.value-plus').on('click', function(){
        var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.value'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)+1;
        if(newVal < <?php echo $estoque; ?>) divUpd.text(newVal);
        });

        $('.value-minus').on('click', function(){
        var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.value'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)-1;
        if(newVal>=1) divUpd.text(newVal);
        });
        </script>
```

Consegui alterar o valor total adicionando quantidade alterando essa linha:

```
$('.value-plus').on('click', function(){
var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.value'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)+1;
if(newVal < <?php echo $numero; ?>) divUpd.text(newVal);
  valor = document.getElementById("produto").innerHTML;
  trocar = valor.replace(",",".");
  valorTotal = trocar * newVal;
  //alert(valorTotal);
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "R$"+valorTotal.toFixed(2);
});
```

Porém quando altero a quantidade por exemplo do produto 1 (200.00), ele multiplica e altera o valor, mas quando altero o produto 2 (270.00), ele apaga o valor do produto 1 e o mesmo ocorre com o produto 3.

Comment: Olá Fox, não seria melhor mandares isto para o lado servidor? Via ajax, porque senão alguém pode mudar o valor na consola facilmente e pode dar dor de cabeça na hora de comprar mesmo, ou até comprar por um valor 0, basta mudar o texto na consola

Comment: Tratando-se de um carrinho de compras, o ideal é validar tanto no lado do cliente quanto no lado do servidor, conforme o @Miguel comentou. Pois assim você garante que ninguém altere o valor e mande um valor errado para o servidor.

Comment: Certo. Na verdade irá alterar no servidor sim, pois os valores do carrinho estão sendo armazenados em uma tabela do BD. Só preciso fazer com que ao alterar a quantidade, os valores sejam corrigidos sem dar refresh na página